# Sending email in django using smtp

Tags: python, django, smtp

on my site i am trying to reset my password by e-mail using smtp but when i send a password change request i get this error:
[image]

here is my settings.py :

```
    EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'

    EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
    EMAIL_PORT = 587
    EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'expresstest177@gmail.com'
    EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "ibuc pvmq fkgb acah"
    EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
    EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
    
    DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
    SERVER_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
    EMAIL_ADMIN = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

and urls.py if needed:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('password-reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
        template_name='main/password_reset_form.html',
        email_template_name='main/password_reset_email.html',
        success_url=reverse_lazy('user:password_reset_done')), name='password_reset'),   

    path('password-reset/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name='main/password_reset_done.html'), name='password_reset_done'),
    path('password-reset/confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
        template_name='main/password_reset_confirm.html',
        success_url=reverse_lazy('user:password_reset_complete')), name='password_reset_confirm'),

    path('password-reset/complete/', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name='main/password_reset_complete.html'), name='password_reset_complete'),
]
```

what could be the problem?

Comment: Did you try removing the empty spaces in the password?

Comment: @GiorgioScarso yes

Comment: It appears to be some connection error, not related to your code (which appears to be fine). Did you try with another internet connection? Try with a mobile hotspot and look if the error perists

Comment: @GiorgioScarso i used mobile hotspot and got this error:

SMTPAuthenticationError at /user/password-reset/
(534, b'5.7.9 Application-specific password required. For more information, go to\n5.7.9  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=InvalidSecondFactor jx24-20020a170906ca5800b00a47152e6d10sm2989024ejb.134 - gsmtp')

Comment: @GiorgioScarso thanks for the tip to use a mobile hotspot, that solved the problem for me